# How do entities get added into another entity in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am working with two similar entities in ASP.NET Core 3.1 with EF Core 3.1 (One-To-Many Relationship):

```
public class Building
{
   public string BuildingId { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
   // other properties
   ...
}

public class Room
{
   public string RoomId { get; set; }
   public virtual Building Building { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey(nameof(Building))]
   public string BuildingId { get; set; }
   // other properties
   ...
}
```

Do `Rooms` provided with a valid `BuildingId` automatically get added into that `Building`'s list? Or do I have to somehow add them manually?

I'm asking in order to get complete objects in my C#:

`var buildings = dbContext.Buildings.Include(b => b.Rooms);`

Comment: @gurkan Yes, but it is recommended to explicitly declare the foreign key in the model. At least for me, it’s easier to just say BuildingId in C# instead of using EF.Property or ChangeTracker.

Comment: I didn’t mention it because my question was about whether or not I can simply set the foreign key and then get an instance of Building with all its Rooms, or I should add the Rooms in the list manually. But thank you, now everything is a little bit clearer.